# how to align headshots inside of div that contains text with different length?

Tags: html, css

i have three div , each contains a head shot image and a text my problem is that the head shots move inside on the div's based upon the amount of text in the div. how can i fix the images in the div's so they are aligned to each other horizontally?
i tried to attach image of my problem but Im not allowed for some## Heading ## reason and the images in my code wont run cause they are local images.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.head-info img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <section class="head-info">
    <div class="one">
      <img src="img-1.png" alt="">
      <p>The AMA’s definitions of marketing and marketing research are reviewed and reapproved/modified every three years by a panel of five scholars who are active researchers.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
      <img src="img-2.png" alt="">
      <p>Marketing is the activity, set of institutions, and processes for creating, communicating, delivering, and exchanging offerings that have value for customers, clients, partners, and society at large. (Approved 2017)</p>
    </div>




    <div class="three">
      <img src="img-3.png" alt="">
      <p>According to the Association of National Advertisers (ANA), influencer marketing focuses on leveraging individuals who have influence over potential buyers and orienting marketing activities around these individuals to drive a brand message to the
        larger market.</p>

    </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWKX2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below CSS in you code?

> section.head-info div {
> width: 50%; }

I hope it may help you.

Comment: no the problem is not with the size of any containers, i know i can posiotion absolute and align the heafshots but i have to align them by eye which i doubt it is a good method surely there must be a better way.

Comment: thank you dear Ambuj for trying to help but i found and solved the problem.best regards to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use span instead of P tag. inline element.
For all div class one, two and three use something like below code :

```
.one, .two, .three {display: inline-flex;}
```

Comment: i have posted the solution to my problem i finally found it. but thanks any way for trying to help it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution to my problem. the problem was that the child divs had different height relative to the parent so i gave the parent a height and set the children's heights to 100% of parents height.
i added border to the parent(green) and children(red) to help visualize them better.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head-info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.head-info img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.head-info div {
  width: 50%;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  

  <section class="head-info">
    <div class="one">
      <img src="img-1.png" alt="">
      <p>The AMA’s definitions of marketing and marketing research are reviewed and reapproved/modified every three years by a panel of five scholars who are active researchers.</p>
    </div>
  
    <div class="two">
      <img src="img-2.png" alt="">
      <p>Marketing is the activity, set of institutions, and processes for creating, communicating, delivering, and exchanging offerings that have value for customers, clients, partners, and society at large. (Approved 2017)</p>
    </div>
  
  
  
  
    <div class="three">
      <img src="img-3.png" alt="">
      <p>According to the Association of National Advertisers (ANA), influencer marketing focuses on leveraging individuals who have influence over potential buyers and orienting marketing activities around these individuals to drive a brand message to the larger market.</p>
  
    </div>
    
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohGva.png)